# Gillman & Jerison on chains of ideals in $C(N)$

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking at problem $\mathbf{2J}$ in Gillman & Jerison's *Rings of Continuous Functions*. Specifically, parts *2* and *3* as follows. (Relevant definitions are at the bottom.)

> *2.* Find a chain of $z$-ideals in $C(\mathbf{Q})$ (under set inclusion) that is in one-to-one, order-preserving correspondence with $\mathbf{R}$.
>
> *3.* Do the same for $C(\mathbf{N})$.

I got a satisfactory solution for *2* by using (1) the a set inclusion-preserving bijection $Z$ between $z$-ideals and $z$-filters described in the definitions and (2) that every closed subset of a metric space is a zero set. Specifically, since the set $\mathbf{Q}\cap [r,\infty)$ is closed in $\mathbf{Q}$ for any $r\in\mathbf{R}$, the $z$-filters on $\mathbf{Q}$ generated by $[r,\infty)$ for all $r\in\mathbf{R}$ give the desired bijection. This preserves order as well, since if $s>r$ and the zero-set $Z(f)\supset [r,\infty)$, $Z(f)\supset [s,\infty)$ as well. That is, $\langle[r,\infty)\rangle\subset\langle[s,\infty)\rangle$.

After thinking for longer than for *2*, I came up with a proof for *3*, which I'll post as an answer below. Given that this problem took longer than most of those I've done out of this book so far, my question is this:

> *Did I miss an easier solution?*

Specifically, is there a nice chain phrased directly in terms of filters or ideals on $\mathbf{N}$, rather than going through a bijection to $\mathbf{Q}$? Thanks for your help.

**Definitions**

A *z-filter* on a topological space $X$ is the intersection of a filter on $X$ with
the set of zero sets of continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbf{R}$.

A *z-ideal* in $C(X)$, the continuous functions mapping $X\to\Bbb{R}$, is an ideal $I$
for which $Z^{-1}(Z(I))=I,$ where $Z(I)$ is the filter of zero sets of functions
in $I$ and $Z^{-1}$ is just the inverse image mapping for $Z$ as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the idea I had for part *3*.

Let $\varphi:\mathbf{N}\to\mathbf{Q}$ be any bijection. It's continuous since $\mathbf{N}$ is discrete. $\varphi$ induces a natural map $\Phi:C(\mathbf{Q})\to C(\mathbf{N})$, where the codomain is just the ring of *all* real-valued functions on $\mathbf{N}$, via $\Phi(f)=f\circ\varphi$. In part *2*, we used the correspondence between $z$-filters and $z$-ideals. Recall the $z$-filters $\langle [r,\infty)\rangle$  from above and let $I_r$ be the corresponding $z$-ideals of $C(\mathbf{Q})$. $\Phi(I_r)$ need not be an ideal of $C(\mathbf{N})$, but I claim the ideals $J_r$ *generated* by the $\Phi(I_r)$ are distinct nevertheless. This is simply because $\varphi$ is a bijection of sets, so that $\Phi$ is injective. Like any function, $\Phi$ preserves set inclusion, and we're done.